# How to find text in two elements based on a condition in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1" ?>
<!-- modified from http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/simple.xml -->
<_breakfastmenu>
<food type="vegetarian">
  <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
  <calories>650</calories>
</food>
<food type="vegetarian">
  <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
  <price>7.95</price>
  <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
  <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food type="vegetarian">
  <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
  <price>8.95</price>
  <description>light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
  <calories>900</calories>
</food>
<food type="vegetarian">
  <name>French Toast</name>
  <price>4.50 </price>
  <description>thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
  <calories>600</calories>
</food>

</_breakfastmenu>
```

I want to find find all of the food elements which contain "Waffles", I can do this successfully by running this XPath:

```
_breakfastmenu/food/name[contains(text(), "Waffles")]
```

But I want to find out the prices for these too, what is the correct way to do this, I have attempted this for a while with no success, any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: are you using an xslt, a programming language e.g. c#, java

Comment: no, just the xml and notepad. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath expression

```
/_breakfastmenu/food[contains(name, 'Waffles')]/price
```

would extract the elements you're interested in.  You generally shouldn't need to use `text()`, since the string value of an element node is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes.  If the element you're looking at might have child elements or more than one text node, for example

```
<foo>This is a <i>contrived</i> example</foo>
```

then the string value of the `foo` element is "This is a contrived example", whereas `foo/text()` would give you two text nodes, "This is a " and " example".  Depending on the context where you are using this node set, you might end up iterating over the nodes or just using the value of the first one ("This is a ").  If you're not sure you need `text()` then you probably don't.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert at this, but will this do?

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("http://localhost:49288/EktronSite2/XMLFiles/Food.xml");//ur xml location
        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("_breakfastmenu/food");
        if(nodes != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                if (node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText.Contains("Waffles"))
                {
                    Response.Write(node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText+ ":" +node.SelectSingleNode("price").InnerText + "<br><br>");
                }
            }
        }
```